# FIRST Why do I get this errorwith Rxjava2 and Retrofit? SECOND Should I be using WeakReference or Activity directly?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

Notice I'm using WeakReference to my context which is an Activity. However, should I be using the Context directly? (no WeakReference)? How should I pass that as a paramter to my createSchoolSearchObservable method too?

```
public void startSearchFeature(Context context) {
    WeakReference<SchoolSearchActivity> activityReference = new WeakReference<>((SchoolSearchActivity) context);
    Disposable disposable = createSchoolSearchObservable(context)
            .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .filter(query -> query.length() >= 2)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .switchMap(new Function<String, ObservableSource<SchoolResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<SchoolResponse> apply(String query) throws Exception {
                    return loadSchools(query);
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(schoolSearchResponse -> {
                List<Node<SchoolSearchResult>> results = schoolSearchResponse.getSchoolSearchResults();
                if (results == null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Results are null");
                }
                if (activityReference.get() != null) {
                    ListAdapter adapter = activityReference.get().binding.schoolAutocompleteSearch.getAdapter();
                    if (adapter instanceof SchoolSearchAdapter) {
                        ((SchoolSearchAdapter) adapter).setSchoolSearchResults(results);
                    } else {
                        activityReference.get()
                                .binding.schoolAutocompleteSearch
                                .setAdapter(SchoolSearchAdapter.newInstance(activityReference.get(), R.layout.school_search_item, results));
                    }
                }
            }, throwable -> {
                Log.e(TAG, throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
            });
    addDisposable(disposable);
}

// https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/RxJava2-Android-Samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rxjava2/android/samples/ui/search/SearchActivity.java
private Observable<String> createSchoolSearchObservable(Context context) {
    WeakReference<SchoolSearchActivity> activityReference = new WeakReference<>((SchoolSearchActivity) context);
    final PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();

    final TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence query, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            Log.d(TAG, query.toString());
            subject.onNext(query.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    };

    final AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener = (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) -> {
            if (parent.getAdapter() == null) {
                subject.onComplete();
                return;
            }
            SchoolSearchResult schoolSearchResult = (SchoolSearchResult) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            SharedPreferences preferences = activityReference.get().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString(activityReference.get().getString(R.string.school_id), schoolSearchResult.getSchoolId());
            editor.putString(activityReference.get().getString(R.string.school_name), schoolSearchResult.getSchoolName());
            editor.apply();
            subject.onComplete();
        };

    activityReference.get().binding.schoolAutocompleteSearch.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    activityReference.get().binding.schoolAutocompleteSearch.setOnItemClickListener(listener);

    return subject;
}


// goes into different viewmodel
private Observable<SchoolResponse> loadSchools(CharSequence query) {
    // load observable from retrofit call
}
```

null
                                                                    java.io.InterruptedIOException
                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.waitForIo(Http2Stream.java:579)
                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeResponseHeaders(Http2Stream.java:143)
                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http2Codec.java:120)
                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:67)
                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                                        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:179)
                                                                        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:63)
                                                                        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
                                                                        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:41)
                                                                        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10910)
                                                                        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
                                                                        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10910)
                                                                        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSwitchMap$SwitchMapObserver.onNext(ObservableSwitchMap.java:126)
                                                                        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDistinctUntilChanged$DistinctUntilChangedObserver.onNext(ObservableDistinctUntilChanged.java:85)
                                                                        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFilter$FilterObserver.onNext(ObservableFilter.java:52)
                                                                        at io.reactivex.observers.SerializedObserver.onNext(SerializedObserver.java:113)
                                                                        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDebounceTimed$DebounceTimedObserver.emit(ObservableDebounceTimed.java:140)
                                                                        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDebounceTimed$DebounceEmitter.run(ObservableDebounceTimed.java:165)
                                                                        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
                                                                        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52)
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace says it all: You are running a network call on the main thread (UI thread) which is not allowed because it blocks the UI.

Use `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` when subscribing.

```
api.getData()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Read more about the difference between `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` [here](https://medium.com/upday-devs/rxjava-subscribeon-vs-observeon-9af518ded53a).

In the future, please also provide the code you used and properly format your post.

Comment: I got a different error this time please help!! Code is provided now